# Adding value to Object value when there is no actually a value to be added

Tags: javascript

Hi I have the following function

```
var f = {i:0}; 
  var t=0; 
  function change(f, t) { 
    f.i++; 
    t++;
}
change(f,t);
```

When I console log is seen the values "f = {i:1}, t=0" May I know how there is 1 is added to i and not in t? Any idea guys? I am totally lost here.

Comment: show the code of `function modify()`

Comment: I don't understand this question - can you post the full code?

Comment: sorry its change not modify

Comment: And by `f.i++` and `t++` did you mean `a.i++` and `b++`?

Comment: Hi Yes Ricky. you are right

Comment: I would advise you to search for some information about "function variable shadowing" and "object pass by reference" for learning.

Answer (score 2):

The is because JavaScript objects are passed by reference while scalar values are passed by value.

So when you pass in objects to functions and mutate them directly you are actually referencing the same object in memory.

```js
var f = {
  i: 0
};
var t = 0;

function change(f, t) {
  f.i++;
  t++;
  console.log(f, t);
}
change(f, t);
console.log(f, t);
```

To avoid accidentally mutating your object, you will have to create a new instance of the object before performing operations on it. There are multiple ways to accomplish this:

- [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)/[spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) you parameter `function({...f}, t)`
- Using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)
- Assign `f` in your function to a [destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) `f` (`f = {...f};`)

For example:

```js
var f = {
  i: 0
};
var t = 0;

function change(f /*{...f}*/, t) {
  f = { ...f};
  // Or alternatively,
  // f = Object.assign({}, f);
  f.i++;
  t++;
  console.log(f, t);
}
change(f, t);
console.log(f, t);
```

It is worth noting that re-assigning your object will not update the value. Please take a look into [Call by sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing).

```js
var f = {
  i: 0
};
var t = 0;

function change(f, t) {
  f = {i: 1};
  t++;
  console.log(f, t);
}
change(f, t);
console.log(f, t);
```

Comment: +1 this is correct. If you did a console.log(t) before you exited the change function t would be equal to 1.

Comment: @MoneyMurch, I shall update to clarify the state of the objects. Thanks for pointing that out :)